# "Bogus Axioms of Continuum Mechanics"

Tags: thermodynamics, continuum-mechanics, specific-reference

In this very interesting IMA Journal of Applied Mathematics article on the sources of irreversibility in thermodynamics [1] L.C. Woods writes

> This author has latterly published two articles on the "Bogus Axioms of Continuum Mechanics" (Woods, 1981b, 1982), to which A. E. Green (1982) has replied, so it will be sufficient here to provide a summary of the points in question, illustrate them with an example, enlarging only where obscurities appear to remain.

His references in the quote above are [2], [3] and [4], all three from "Bull. IMA" but I have not been able to locate any of these. Can somebody help me to find them?

[1] Woods: "Thermodynamic Inequalities in Continuum Mechanics", IMA Journal of Applied Mathematics (1982) 29, 221-246

[2] WOODS, L. C. 1981b Bull. IMA, 17, 98-102.

[3] WOODS, L. C. 1982 Bull. IMA. 18, 64-66.

[4] GREEN, A. E. 1982 Bull. IMA 18, 7-9, 154.

Comment: Bull. may be short for bulletin. the bulletin of the institute of mathematics is my guess. i personally never have any luck finding those.

Comment: This appears to be the [*Bulletin of the Institute of Mathematics and its Applications*](https://aperiodical.com/2012/03/ima-bulletin-volume-1-issue-1-2/), which was re-titled *Mathematics Today* in 1996.  If you can't find it under that name, perhaps consult your local ILL office.